# What if I don't know what tag(s) my question relates to?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Especially as a non-expert still learning the language, how should I tag certain questions when I have no idea what the correct terminology for the topic is? I often even do not know what an appropriate English grammar tag name would be.

Comment: Don't worry too much about it. There are many users with the ability to re-tag the questions for you if there are better alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, while you are writing your question there are automatically generated suggestions that show questions similar to the one you are currently writing. Perhaps you can take a look at other questions and observe what tags are appropriate for that type of question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the list of tags on JLU - https://japanese.stackexchange.com/tags. Almost all of the most popular tags have a description so you can know what it's for.

Also, there are a lot of straight forward tags, like [katakana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/katakana) if you're asking about something related to katakana (I know it's your favorite!).

You are only required to use one tag when you submit a question. You should be able to find at least one straight forward tag for your question. And, like @Flaw said in the comments, there are users who will add tags for you. I know this happened to me a lot when I first joined JLU. Maybe try to watch your questions to see if this happens and learn from the tags that were added.

If you need further help with understanding a tag, you could always ask in meta or in Chat.